# Android - ListView inside Gallery makes the scrolling not Smooth

Tags: android

I implemented a gallery, and inside it I have many listviews from left to right.
For some reason Gallery works great with all views but not with listview.
With listview, when scrolling on the gallery, sometimes I get little jumps.

Anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

some notes:  The gallery uses an adapter to find out what to show, and then the listview is created based on the adapter

Thanks

Comment: Some code would be helpful. And a screenshot to understand what "listviews inside gallery" means.

Comment: What gesturedetector are you referring to here? @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
return groupGalleryView.getGestureDetector().onTouchEvent(event);
} I seriously cant remove the flicker when the listview is in the gallery! Even when the listview is list.setClickable(false);
list.setEnable(false); i get the flicker! Aaarghhh ANDROIDDD bugggyness!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrollable items inside of other scrollable items tends to have problems. I am not surprised that this does not work well.

Comment: I tried the other way around and it works great.
I put 1 list view, and in each item, I draw a gallery, and its amazing how well it works.  I look at the android source code, and they are implemented different, so that is why is the reason one works and the other doesn't.  I guess I will need to build a custom Layout.  Any suggestions for this? thanks

Comment: @CommonsWare what would be the better option, sir?

Comment: @Gaurav: `Gallery` has been deprecated. `ListViews` as pages in a `ViewPager` should work.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue.  The problem is that the ListView is intercepting touch events from your Gallery and modifying the view position in its block of code that deals with the vertical scrolling of the ListView.  If only Gallery intercepted the touch event first... I consider this a bug in the Android source, but in the meantime you can fix the un-smooth scrolling by subclassing Gallery and using your subclass instead.  This will do the trick:

```
public class BetterGallery extends Gallery {
    private boolean scrollingHorizontally = false;

    public BetterGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public BetterGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public BetterGallery(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        return scrollingHorizontally;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        scrollingHorizontally = true;
        return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            scrollingHorizontally = false;
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Also, set something like this in the activity that implements the gallery:

```
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.users);
    listView.setAdapter(userListAdapter);
    listView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        galleryView.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
        }           
    });
```

Finally, add onTouchEvent() to the activity itself:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
return galleryView.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

One final note... After implementing this fully, I found that from a usability perspective, it was better to extend ViewAnimator with a custom class I called AdaptableViewAnimator, that of course just had some adapter functionality baked-in, and embed the ListView inside it.  It doesn't float around as much as the ListView-inside-Gallery.

Comment: have implemented this and the scrolling works well however this Gallery will not scroll left and right.

Comment: I edited the answer with an additional requirement Michael.  Thanks for the feedback

Comment: hello,can you put the xml,i also want to do this effect,can you give me your help,it can save me much time thank you

Comment: Correction to the bottom two code blocks: gallery IS the gestureDetector, so the two references should be:   galleryView.onTouchEvent(event);

Comment: +1 for mentioning" un-smooth scrolling " before write a code ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had have the same problem. And the solution is less than simple.

1. - Set the listview to be not focusable in touch mode.

   `listView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);`

   - If you need focus, call it from onItemSelected listener.
2. Use OnInterceptTouchEvent to get Touch Events from your child. And make some modification in onScroll and onTouchEvent of your Gallery

   ```
   OnItemSelectedListener mOnItemSelected = new OnItemSelectedListener()
   {   
       @Override
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
               int position, long id)
       {
         view.requestFocusFromTouch();
       }
       @Override
       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
       {               
       }
   };

   @Override
   public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
       onTouchEvent(ev);
       return scrollingHorizontally;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
       if(Math.abs(distanceX)>Math.abs(distanceY) || scrollingHorizontally == true){
           scrollingHorizontally = true;
           super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
       }
       return scrollingHorizontally;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
       switch(event.getAction()) {
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
           scrollingHorizontally = false;
           break;
       default:
               break;
       }
       super.onTouchEvent(event);
       return scrollingHorizontally;
   }
   ```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! Better than jkschneider's solution which allowed the Gallery to witness the scroll events from the ListView, but had some weird "bouncing" effects and resistance to scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
listView.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
```