# Android GalleryView that contains scrollable views, e.g. ListView

Tags: android, listview, galleryview

I managed to implement a GalleryView, create a custom Adapter that returns a ListView for each item of the gallery but now the the problem:

I while I can scroll the listview vertially, I can no longer scroll the GalleryView horizontally.

What I am aiming at is a UI similar to the Google Weather/News application. While you can click a 'tab-like' gallery item on the top, you can also horizontally scroll the list views that represent the news items.

How can I implement this?

Comment: potentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249832/android-listview-inside-gallery-makes-the-scrolling-not-smooth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t know the Google Weather/News app, but if I understand you correctly a ViewFlipper/ViewAnimator could help you.

Comment: I think the issue is that both vertical and horizontal movement / touch has to be tracked, but by different ui controls.