# Android: ListViews inside Gallery - how to get scrolling, clicking and swiping like in GTalk?

Tags: android, listview, scroll, gallery, swipe

I am writing an Android application, and I use ListViews inside a Gallery. The ListViews represent chat windows. I would really like to be able to swipe between the chat windows in the Gallery, while also being able to scroll in the ListView or click single messages.
While searching, I found a guy here on Stackoverflow that was kind enough to provide his solution to this problem:
[Android - ListView inside Gallery makes the scrolling not Smooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249832/android-listview-inside-gallery-makes-the-scrolling-not-smooth)

His BetterGallery almost works out for me. Clicking a list item works and scrolling the list view works. I currently have two issues to iron out with this implementation:

1)  When swiping in the gallery, the movement is not smooth and it is not always certain which List View it will end up displaying.

2)  You can both swipe and scroll at the same time in the same finger movement by e.g. moving your finger diagonally.

As a note to point 2: The behavior I am looking for is something similar to the chat windows that you can find in GTalk. In GTalk, you can either do scrolling inside a chat, or swiping between different chats, in one movement. That means if you start scrolling, moving your finger from side to side will not swipe. Similarly, starting a swipe will block scrolling until you release the finger and start a new gesture.

Has anyone achieved something similar to how it works in GTalk?

Best wishes!

Answer (score 1):

I had have the same problem. And the solution is less than simple.

1. - Set the listview to be not focusable in touch mode.

   `listView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);`

   - If you need focus, call it from onItemSelected listener.

2. - Use OnInterceptTouchEvent to get Touch Events from your child. And make some modification in onScroll and onTouchEvent

```
    
    OnItemSelectedListener mOnItemSelected = new OnItemSelectedListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view,
                        int position, long id)
                {
                  view.requestFocusFromTouch();
                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent)
                {

                }
            };
```

```
    
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        onTouchEvent(ev);
        return scrollingHorizontally;
    }
```

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    if(Math.abs(distanceX)>Math.abs(distanceY) || scrollingHorizontally == true){
        scrollingHorizontally = true;
        super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
    }
    return scrollingHorizontally;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        scrollingHorizontally = false;
        break;
    default:
            break;
    }
    super.onTouchEvent(event);
    return scrollingHorizontally;
}